# Fire HashChangeEvent in dart

Tags: dart, dart-html, hashchange

I'm using straight dart:html and I'm looking for a way to fire a HashChangeEvent.

I'm already handling the hash change event:

```dart
  window.onHashChange.listen((HashChangeEvent e) {
    hashChange(window.location.hash);
  });
```

Now I'm looking for a way to change the hash when clicking on a button as example:

```dart
querySelector("#some-button").onClick.listen((e) => changeHash("#something"));
```

All the articles I've found so far shows how to handle the HashChangeEvent.

Comment: You don't want to set a new hash using `window.location.hash='something'`?

Comment: Of course, forgot that dart is using properties instead of getters and setters. That works for me, thanks Gunter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `hash` part of `window.location` the event is fired.

```dart
window.location.hash = 'something'
```